# WD19TB not charguing on Ubuntu 20.04, Dell XPS 15 laptop

Tags: 20.04, dell, docking

Everything else is working fine (monitors, keyboard, etc..).

The computer said it's charging, but it doesn't.

[image: uno]

Comment: I'm using the WD19TB docking station, this one delivers the correct power. I check and there's a recurrent problem with this model and it's a hardware problem in the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's a recurrent problem in the motherboard of [XPS 15-9570](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-9570-TB16-USB-Type-C-no-longer-charging/td-p/7317594) that makes impossible to deliver charge trough the USB-C port.

If you have a similar problem with a Dell computer, use your warranty before expired. They offer no solution afterward.